# How to open mapped network Drive in windows explorer using java

Tags: java

I have shared network drive. In windows we will open network drive using run command `(Example "\\ipAddress")`. something similar to it I need to open network drive in windows explorer through java.

Answer (score 1):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\\ipAddress");
```

should do it.

Comment: or perhaps `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"explorer", "\\localhost"});`